# xSAP error passing an smv model

Tags: python, nusmv

I was trying to pass to xSAP (version 1.2.0) an smv model, but I got this error

```
panda@jakul:~/Desktop$ python /home/panda/Desktop/xSAP/scripts/extend_model.py -v /home/panda/Desktop/brca.smv /home/panda/Desktop/brca.fei 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/panda/Desktop/xSAP/scripts/extend_model.py", line 211, in <module> if not args.xml_fei   
File "/home/panda/Desktop/xSAP/scripts/extend_model.py", line 41, in translate_fei_to_xml fei_txt_fname, out_fei_xml, path) 
File "/hardmnt/mitchell0/home/zampedri/ESTools/scripts/out/build/ESTools/xSAP/win64/xSAP-bin/code/feic/translate/fei_translator.py", line 46, in convert_fei_text_to_xml_format   
File "/hardmnt/mitchell0/home/zampedri/ESTools/scripts/out/build/ESTools/xSAP/win64/xSAP-bin/code/feic/translate/fei_translator.py", line 793, in get_library_manager   
File "/hardmnt/mitchell0/home/zampedri/ESTools/scripts/out/build/ESTools/xSAP/win64/xSAP-bin/code/feic/fe/lib_mgr/libraries/manager.py", line 80, in __init__   
File "/hardmnt/mitchell0/home/zampedri/ESTools/scripts/out/build/ESTools/xSAP/win64/xSAP-bin/code/feic/fe/lib_mgr/libraries/manager.py", line 120, in __loadEml   
File "/hardmnt/mitchell0/home/zampedri/ESTools/scripts/out/build/ESTools/xSAP/win64/xSAP-bin/code/feic/fe/lib_mgr/utils/utils.py", line 30, in LoadXML 
File "src/lxml/lxml.objectify.pyx", line 1838, in lxml.objectify.parse (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:25528)   
File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79841)   
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1793, n lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116175)  
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in xml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116525)   
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1723, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:115413)  
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1126, in xml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110110)   
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 584, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103584) 
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 694, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105238)   
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 624, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:104147)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Element 'effects_model', attribute 'name': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:NCName'.
```

The model works just fine with NuSMV (version 2.6.0). I don't understand if I have to pass to xSAP an xml file (and if so, how do I translate the smv in an xml file?) or if there is some other error.

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert about Python API of XSAP, however it seems to me you are missing an XML file in input. It may be that you are missing the **"Fault Modes file (xml format) which must be specified when invoking the tool."**

You should take a look at https://es-static.fbk.eu/tools/xsap/downloads/xsap-manual.pdf at Chapter 3.1 where you can find the sentece I quoted *and* the specification for the file you are missing.